# Finding the third vertex of a isosceles triangle given the vertices of the base and knowing that the medians are perpendicular

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

**Full problem:**
The points A(0, c) and B(c, 0) are the vetrices of the base of an isosceles triangle. In addition, the medians AD and BE are perpendicular to each other.
What are the coordinates of the third vertex?

[image]

Even if I figure out the lengths of all sides, medians included, how do I find the coordinates of the vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the third vertex $C$ will lie on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, so it will be of the form $(d,d)$. The midpoint $F$ of $AB$ is $(\frac{c}{2},\frac{c}{2})$. The centroid $G$ of the triangle is one third of the way from $F$ to $C$. Now figure out what $d$ must be for $AGB$ to be right.

Comment: Does the bisector of AB intersect the right angle into two angles of the same measure?

Comment: The perpendicular bisector of a line segment is a line which passes though the midpoint of that segment and is perpendicular to it.

Comment: However... 
I have just realized that there might be another solution. 
The reflection of point C in the negative part of coordinate plane would work, too, wouldn't it?

Comment: And why does this point have to be of the form (d, d)? 
Is it not possible, that the slope of the bisector the vertex will lie on will be different than 1?

Comment: I left this for you to justify. In short, line $AB$ has slope $-1$, so every line perpendicular to it - in particular the perpendicular bisector - must have slope $1$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Extend $\overline{AD}$ to $\overline{AE}$ such that $AD = DE$.
2. Bisect $\overline{DE}$ at point $G$.
3. Draw line $\overleftrightarrow{BG}$
4. Intersect line $\overleftrightarrow{BG}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ at point F.